# Creating Access Database Copies with different uniqueID

Tags: database, ms-access, primary-key

I have multiple access databases with approximately 30 tables each. Each database corresponds to an airplane and its allied tables. Most of the data in these tables is same. Hence, I would just like to change the UniqueID of the first (perfect/tested) database in order to have the same structure for rest of the databases (along with Data) and have multiple databases ready.

I tried the following:
1. Importing data: This creates copies of the data-tables in the new database and then they have to be renamed plus the uniqueID problem persists.

2. Broke all relationships of the main table, changed the Primary Key and again proceeded to add relationships. This is somehow not a good solution as it complicates the work.
3. Copied data by modifying tables in Excel and then pasting data in Access. In this I kept a lookout for the IDs in each table and modified accordingly. This is also a tedious process.

I am looking for a good solution and suggestions. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why have a database for each airplane? Why not one database for all planes? What data is copied - lookup tables? Why does any UniqueID even have to be changed - changed to what? Is this an autonumber field and you want a different seed value so doesn't start with 1? Why?

Comment: To compliment June7's questions, do the UnqiueID values need to be unique across all databases?  If the answer is no, why not just copy the entire access database file?  That would create an exact copy of all tables and relationships, leaving them intact without the need for importing, updating, reconciling.